# How to insert more than one value for a select dropdown

Tags: php, select, smarty, hidden-field

I can't seem to find a workaround for this.

I have a smarty based script that im using.

I am trying somehow submit 2 values from a form that is on my submit post page. I am actually successfully posting several fields into the "posts" table already from my current form.

However, here's where my problem is, I need to get both the category name and the category id into to their own columns. Right now I can only choose one or the other.

My form contains this :

```
<select name="category" id="category" >
    {section name=i loop=$msgcat}
        <option value="{$msgcat[i].catname|stripslashes}">{$msgcat[i].catname|stripslashes}</option>
    {/section}
</select>
```

Which will render this in html as :

```
<select id="category" name="category">
<option value="Car">Car</option>
<option value="Truck">Truck</option>
<option value="Boat">Boat</option>
<option value="Motorcycle">Motorcycle</option>
<option value="RV">RV</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way in this same form I can have a hidden input field called catid which could assign the associated category id "value" based on which "category" drop down selection is made?

Something like "if category selection = Car, then hidden input value = 1" (would have to include a rule for each dropdown selection)

Would this be done in php? javascript?

Is there a much better way to do what im trying to do?

Right now the "category" drop down field gets submitted properly to the "posts" table into the "category" column. Respectively, I need the catid to go into the "catid" column in the same table.

The catid is a defined value for each category, e.g. Car=1, Truck=2, Boat=3...

Where 1 is the catid for "Car" ...and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have both `category` and a `catid` column in your `posts` table? You should normalize your table. Only have `catid` in your `posts` table and reference it in a `categories` table.

If you don't normalize, later on, what if you decide to rename your category `Car` to `Sedan`. Then you will have to change every `category` column in your `posts` table. If you normalize, you will only need to change one row in your `categories` table, and change that `Car` to `Sedan` and all your posts will show the updated category name.

Example `posts` table:

```
id | catid | title | content | date
1  | 1     | something about cars | the content of the post | 2013-10-01
```

Example `categories` table:

```
id | name
1  | Car
2  | Truck
3  | Boat
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

If you don't want a normalized database, then in your select dropdown, you pass your `catid`, and in your PHP script, get the ID and look for the corresponding category name from the `categories` table.

**UPDATE**

Use MySQL JOIN to get the category name while pulling your post.

To get all posts:

```
SELECT posts.*, categories.name as category FROM posts p JOIN categories c ON p.catid = c.id
```

To get a post by ID:

```
SELECT posts.*, categories.name as category FROM posts p JOIN categories c ON p.catid = c.id WHERE posts.id = YOUR_ID
```

Then when display your post, you can just do:

echo `$post['category']` and it will print out the category name

**UPDATE 2**

Then do as @jeff says. Put a pipe in your SELECT OPTION values.

```
<select name="category">
<option value="1|Car">
<option value="2|Truck">
</select>
```

In your PHP, do the following:

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
//Explode the category, this will generate an array 
$category = explode('|', $category);
//the $category will result in array('1', 'Car')
$cat_id = $category[0];
$cat_name = $category[1];
//Now you have both your category ID and Name
```

Read up on [PHP Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: I do have a category table that is seperate that has the category name and the catid, but I ran into a problem on another page when trying to get the info I needed, because I was trying to show on the post the category name and have that hyperlink to pull all posts under that category it wasn't working properly. So, I had to do this, even though I agree it should be better. At this point I just need a hack to make it work.

Comment: Updated my answer to use JOINS

Comment: I truly appreciate your advice. But I really can't seem to follow. If I could just add the catid to the posts table and keep categories in there as it as (for now) ....then I can complete what I need to achieve. I just need to find out how I can pass the cat id based on the selection. I don't understand how to join as you illustrated. I am displaying all the posts with the category name on them, once clicked the category name shows all posts in that category by using the catid. I just need the catid in the same table.

Comment: If you are going to use both the `catid` and the `categoryname` in the `posts` table, then why do you even have a `category` table?

Comment: because it was orginally intended to work differently, until I ran into this problem. So, creating this hack will render that table useless for now. But, I will have to fix later. Right now, I just need to complete.

Comment: got your "update 2" to work. Many Thanks. I was trying javascript unsuccessfully like this : 

`<script type="text/javascript">
function category() {
var isselected = category.options[categoryeval.selectedIndex].text;
if (isselected=="Car") {categoryval.text="1"}
if (isselected=="Truck") {categoryval.text="2"}
if (isselected=="Boat") {categoryeval.text="3"}
}
</script>`
 and adding this to my select `onchange="category.value=options[selectedIndex].value;categoryval.value=options[selectedIndex].text"`

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't know what your javascript does. But you cannot send two values from an SELECT element.

Comment: Amazing answer, this saves my time.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the information within the value attribute. I use the | to separate the data and on the server-side split this information out. Assumming that you are using $msgcat[i].catid as your id variable

```
<select name="category" id="category" >
    {section name=i loop=$msgcat}
        <option value="{$msgcat[i].catid}|{$msgcat[i].catname|stripslashes}">{$msgcat[i].catname|stripslashes}</option>
    {/section}
</select>
```

Comment: then how would I enter just the catid into its own column in that table? That is what is needed, because I am displaying the category on the front end of the website. So I don't want it to be displayed as 1 Car. I want to be able to display how I currently have it "category name" and be able to create a hyperlink for that by grabbing the catid like this `<a href="{$baseurl}/category.php?c={$posts[i].catid|stripslashes}">{$posts[i].category|stripslashes}</a>`